# ReportServer, ReportServerTempDB

Tags: sql-server

I have MS SQL Server 2008 installed on my machine and also ‘Reporting Services Configuration Manager’.
When I connect to (local) instance with Windows Authentication, I see following two DBs already available in this instance –
- ReportServer
- ReportServerTempDB

Do they come as a part of Reporting Services Configuration Manager?

Thank you!

Comment: This belongs on Database Administrators

Comment: @JohnHartsock These are standard SSRS databases. No need to moved to DBA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those databases are created when you install SQL Server Reporting Services.

read more here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159093.aspx